# jquery Recursively filter with tab-switch

Tags: jquery, search, filter

I'm not great with JQuery but I've got quite far this time..

I'm trying to get the below to display the search result when typed, which it kind of does if you type 'rob' and click 'B'. The alphabetical selector works ok:

http://tm.eth3r.co.uk/test3.html

I've popped all the code here, which might be easier to view:
http://jsfiddle.net/ro6er/gQ6Nc/
(ignore all the css, straight from wordpress)

Here's the jquery:

```
$(function() {
    //a-z switcher
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.navigation-tabs a').click(function(){
            switch_tabs($(this));
            return false;
        });
        switch_tabs($('.default-tab'));  
    });
    function switch_tabs(obj)
    {   

            $('.tab-content').hide();


        $('.navigation-tabs a').removeClass("selected");
        var id = obj.attr("data-custom-attr");
        $('#'+id).show();
        obj.addClass("selected");
    }
    //a-z switcher
        if ($("#searchInput").keyup)
        {

 //Declare the custom selector 'containsIgnoreCase'.
      $.expr[':'].containsIgnoreCase = function(n,i,m){
          return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
      };

      $("#searchInput").keyup(function(){
 //hide all the rows
          $(".tab-content").find("table").hide();

 //split the current value of searchInput
          var data = this.value.split(" ");
 //create a jquery object of the rows
          var jo = $(".tab-content").find("table");
 //Recursively filter the jquery object to get results. 
          $.each(data, function(i, v){
               jo = jo.filter("*:containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')");
          });
 //show the rows that match.
          jo.show();
 //Removes the placeholder text 
      }).focus(function(){
          this.value="";
          $(this).css({"color":"black"});
          $(this).unbind('focus');
      }).css({"color":"#C0C0C0"});
        }

});
```

Comment: I think you are searching too much.  Are you trying to search everything in the table or just by name?  Are you trying to search by letter or search everything each letter. It looks like it is only searching the letter you are currently have selected.

Comment: If you want the search box to search EVERYTHING (all tables, etc) then I think you need to take your searchInput function out of your tab switch function, because right now it is only searching the content only under the tab you are currently on not the whole block of tables.

Comment: The way it searches is ok for the purpose, it just needs to run through some tables. All the function is in place. I just need a hand displaying the result when you actually search. Here's where I got the search code from and then adapted it if you're interested http://marceble.com/2010/jqueryfilter/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to target different div's. I've updated my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ro6er/gQ6Nc/

User test and pass in search box or A and B to see the results.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  //a-z switcher

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navigation-tabs a').click(function(){
      switch_tabs($(this));
      return false;
    });
    switch_tabs($('.default-tab'));  
  });
  function switch_tabs(obj)
  { 

      $('.tab-content').hide();


    $('.navigation-tabs a').removeClass("selected");
      var id = obj.attr("data-custom-attr");
    $('#'+id).show();
    obj.addClass("selected");
  }
  //a-z switcher

  if ($("#searchInput").keyup)
    {
 //Declare the custom selector 'containsIgnoreCase'.
      $.expr[':'].containsIgnoreCase = function(n,i,m){
          return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
      };

      $("#searchInput").keyup(function(){
 //hide all the rows
          $("#searchblock").find(".tab-content").hide();

 //split the current value of searchInput
          var data = this.value.split(" ");
 //create a jquery object of the rows
          var jo = $("#searchblock").find(".tab-content");
 //Recursively filter the jquery object to get results. 
          $.each(data, function(i, v){
               jo = jo.filter("*:containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')");
          });
 //show the rows that match.
          jo.show();
 //Removes the placeholder text 
      }).focus(function(){
          this.value="";
          $(this).css({"color":"black"});
          $(this).unbind('focus');
      }).css({"color":"#C0C0C0"});
    }
  });
```

I'm ace.

Roger

Comment: I see, you weren't trying to search ALL items in the search table, just under each letter.  Would it be more conducive to have people just type in what they are looking for without each letter being selected. Or maybe have an "ALL" tab that searches everything in all the tables.  Kind of like a general search?  Instead of just by letter?  Just a thought.  But it is your project. Good job figuring it out and posting your fix. Will help others in the future.

Comment: Honestly the client will probably change their mind before any logic is applied to the current situation but I get what you're saying. Thanks for your support :)